# socket connect failed for: /tmp/osm-renderd

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, mapnik

I have installed Mapnik and have a functioning PostGIS database (I can access data through QGIS with no problems). When I try to run render_list to generate tiles it fails with

socket connect failed for: /tmp/osm-renderd

I have updated datasource-settings.xml.inc to include proper connection settings for my database but still no luck.

Here is my datasource-settings.xml.inc:

```
<!--
Settings for your postgres setup.

Note: feel free to leave password, host, port, or use blank
-->

<Parameter name="type">postgis</Parameter>
<Parameter name="password">gis</Parameter>
<Parameter name="host">localhost</Parameter -->
<Parameter name="port">5432</Parameter -->
<Parameter name="user">www-data</Parameter>
<Parameter name="dbname">gis_data</Parameter>
<!-- this should be 'false' if you are manually providing the 'extent' -->
<Parameter name="estimate_extent">true</Parameter>
<!-- manually provided extent in epsg 900913 for whole globe -->
<!-- providing this speeds up Mapnik database queries -->
<!-- Parameter name="extent">%(extent)s</Parameter -->
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. My database is on localhost at port 5432. OSM data is located in a database called gis_data under a schema called osm_data. The tables all have public permissions so I don't see that being the issue. Googling around didn't yield much help other than double- and triple-checking the permissions on my database. Any suggestions? Is there another settings file somewhere that I need to be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to /etc/init.d/renderd as sudo, then run render_list as sudo as well. I've also gotten it to work by doing both of the above as the www-data user.